# Why won't Jquery work with Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm really just not sure why this code isn't working in my JSFiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Just going to say it, the downvotes are really discouraging. I don't know as much as I should, I suppose (or at least not as much as some deem worthy), but asking questions is how I will understand more. What's wrong with that?

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="test">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $(".test").css("height", "100px")
}]);
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/td5n6cf8/

Comment: Learn to use your Browser's console.  It will show you that `$ is not defined`, which means that jQuery was not included.

Comment: @cale_b Is JQuery not included in AngularJS? If not, how do I include both JQuery and Angular in JSFiddle?

Comment: jqLite is included in Angular, but I recall reading something recently about the way JSFiddle does it - google "JSFiddle Angular jQuery", I bet you'll find the answer you need.

Comment: @AGE - you are right.  My comment about console was not intended to be difficult.  Using the console is a **game changer** - I remember coding when there WAS no console, and issues like this were impossible to sort out.  It was meant to encourage the OP to start using it, because it will make their life tremendously easier!  Sorry for coming off short or impatient - not my intent at all.

Comment: @cale_b I appreciate your help! My edit was not directed towards you at all.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the downvotes.  Sorry! (I did not downvote, FYI - was just trying to help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution mate, you just forgot to add the JQuery library to your JSFiddle.

To add it in JSFiddle on the left hand navigation bar, where it says **External Resources** and throw in the URL: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js

Alternatively (and more practical outside JSFiddle):

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="test">
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Easy does it.

Disclaimer: use a valid CDN or download whichever JQuery version you like, as of today JQuery 3.0.0-alpha1 is the latest version

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate the understanding for asking a simple question.